# Running named macro in Application.OnTime generates "The macro may not be available in this workbook"

Tags: excel, vba

My macro is to update text imported from a website every second.

It produces this error:

> Cannot run the macro "'/Users/(name)/Desktop/(foldername)/Book1.xlsx'!List1.UpdateCell". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

```vb
Sub UpdateCell()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:1"), "List1.UpdateCell"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your Application.OnTime, the second parameter that holds procedure stored as a string, throws that error, `"List1.UpdateCell"` revise and correct it.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the **"List1.UpdateCell"** to just **"UpdateCell"**.